# jqplot draw vertical line in graph

Tags: javascript, jqplot

My program is drawing a graph with the following (comparable) source code from the jqplot page. The goal is to draw a vertical line at position x in the graph. I followed up the guide an examples on the jqplot page, but it didn't draw the line, just the graph.

Is someone experienced with that? Or could tell me how the options/calls should be to get the line in the graph?

Example-code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var plot2 = $.jqplot ('chart2', [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]], {
      // Give the plot a title.
      title: 'Plot With Options',
      // You can specify options for all axes on the plot at once with
      // the axesDefaults object.  Here, we're using a canvas renderer
      // to draw the axis label which allows rotated text.
      axesDefaults: {
        labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
      },
      // An axes object holds options for all axes.
      // Allowable axes are xaxis, x2axis, yaxis, y2axis, y3axis, ...
      // Up to 9 y axes are supported.
      axes: {
        // options for each axis are specified in seperate option objects.
        xaxis: {
          label: "X Axis",
          // Turn off "padding".  This will allow data point to lie on the
          // edges of the grid.  Default padding is 1.2 and will keep all
          // points inside the bounds of the grid.
          pad: 0
        },
        yaxis: {
          label: "Y Axis"
        }
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding this to your existing code should help you draw a vertical line.

CODE:

```
canvasOverlay: {
   show: true,
   objects: [
       {verticalLine: {
           name: 'stack-overflow',
           x: 4, // x-axis position where you want to draw the vertical line.
           lineWidth: 6,
           color: 'rgb(100, 55, 124)',
           shadow: false
       }}
    ]
}
```

You can set the 'x' to a desired value of your choice.

IMP: In order for the `canvasOverlay` to work, you must include the `jqplot.canvasOverlay.min.js` file, else it will not work.

Here's a working fiddle: [jqPlot - Draw vertical line on the graph](http://jsfiddle.net/anish_nair/61h37kkn/)

I included the following files in code above(JS Fiddle). You can also refer to the External Resources section on the left pane in JSFiddle.

- jquery.jqplot.min.js
- jquery.jqplot.min.css
- jqplot.canvasOverlay.min.js
- jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js
- jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js

jqPlot Example here - [jqPlot Canvas Overlay](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/canvas-overlay.html)

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: Hi @Anish Nair , I needed to wait until today, before I could test it.
The problem was that I Forget to include the jqplot.canvasOverlay.min.js

Comment: hi @AnishNair is it posiblie to add a horizontal line in y2 or y3 axes? I tried that with no luck.

Comment: @gabodevv Haven't tried it yet. Also skimmed through the jqplot docs, didn't find any option to set the axes(y1, y2, y3).
If you want to draw a horizontal line on the y2 axis, just do some mathematics.

Say your `y1 axes range is : 0 - 100` and
`y2 axes is : 0 - 200`
And you want to plot a horizontal line on` y2 axes at 60`

So do : `(y1 max / y2 max) * value`
Which is `(100/200) * 60 = 30`

If y1's max is greater than y2's max, the formula will change.

Comment: How to fix the same line x2axis vertically